# Why a nested span inside a div does not follow line-height rule for that div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with font size of 88 and line height of 88. The text inside the div has a height taller than 88. Why is this?

```
<div style="font-size:88px;line-height:88px;">I need <span sytle="color:red;">videos</span></div>
```

If you open up the element inspector and highlight the parent div, it is 88px tall. However if you highlight the text "I need" and the nested span, the height is 101px. This remains true even if you set the line-height on the span itself:

```
<div style="font-size:88px;line-height:88px;">
  I need <span style="font-size:88px;line-height:88px;color:red;">videos</span>
</div>
```

See attached repl: https://repl.it/@teeej/ReliablePunctualRam

Comment: for one you are missing a " on your span style

Comment: @Icewine Fixed but that has zero effect on my question and the issue still remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<span>` is, by default, an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements).

If you expect it to behave like an inline block element, you have to give it a `display` value of `inline-block` and it will have a height of exactly `88px`:

```css
div > span { 
  display: inline-block; 
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:88px;line-height:88px;">
      I need <span style="font-size:88px;line-height:88px;">videos</span>
</div>
```

For a better understanding of the implications of `display` property, I recommend the [Candidate Recommendation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/). And here's the current (official) [Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Comment: Why does the span element get a different height when it is set to inline?

Comment: The simple answer is: because that's how inline content works. The technical answer is to be found in the docs for [inline-formatting](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) and [line-height](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Ok yes I see that, why does the "I need" show up in the inspector with quote and still have a height of 101? See image: https://imgur.com/a/i2B98In

Comment: Because Chrome now gives you info about text nodes contained in block level elements, like they would be separate elements (they are separate nodes, but they are not HTML elements). However, the text node ***is*** an *inline* element, but don't mistake it for the `<div>` itself, which has a height of exactly `88px`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Any way around that? My issue is I am setting a click event on the "I need" text, but it is stacked directly below another element with a click event. But because the "I need" text is still reading at 101px, it is bleeding over into the element above and making the click event inaccurate.

Comment: Repeating style is redundant.

Comment: @Thielicious I get that, it was only as an example. The question is more about how the nested span affects the other text in the div. See comments above.

Comment: @Thielicious, I haven't touched the provided code **on purpose**, to demonstrate the issue and not distract by changing the initially more than necessary to explain what's going on.

Comment: @taptaptap, there is absolutely no way a click outside of the `88px` of the `<div>` will trigger on the `<div>` if you click inside what looks like the space occupied by the `inline` content of the div which apparently overflows the `<div>`. It looks like you've presenting us an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Don't you think it would have been better to ask about the issue at hand (the click problem)?

Comment: I get what you are saying but the issue with the click is directly because the issue with the element's height. After digging a little further, I have discovered that adding a sudo :after element to the nested span is what is causing it to do the quotes thing you talked about with Chrome, which is causing my issue. I think I can figure it out from here. Thanks for your help.